# How to log coordinates requested on a layer's feature

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, openlayers-3

I want to log the coordinates each time I click on a feature on my map. What I do is:

When I click on the map I do call the `map.on('singleclick')` function and get the featureInfo from the layer's features returned. The returned object looks like this:

```
geometry: Object
coordinates: Array[1]
type: "MultiPolygon
geometry_name: "the_geom"
id: "Kreise.5"
```

Where the coordinates array contains the desired coordinates. Then I call a function that will push the attributes: layer, geometry_name and coordinates to a geometry array.

```
var setGeometry = function (layer, geom, flatCoordinates) {
                var geometry = [];
                geometry.push([{
                    layer: layer,
                    geom: angular.uppercase(geom),
                    flatCoordinates: setFlatCoordinates(flatCoordinates)
                }]);
                console.log(geometry);                
            };
```

Unfortunately, everytime I click on the map and this function is called, it won't add new geometry objects to this array, it just overwrites the old attributes.

I tried to push these attributes to a local array in the `map.on('singleclick')` function which will work as intended, but I'd like to have a solution which calls the function above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, by re-reading this question I noticed that I should have declared the geometry array outside the called function. Since calling the function will always instantiate a new array and overwrite the old one.

Comment: just define $scope.geometry as array in your controller and then use it where u need